# unable to connect with mysql database using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to connect my android application that has a Login page connected to a database using php. It is getting connected to the DB. but it is not retrieving all the coloumns from the table. Instead only two coloumns are fetched. following is the code

```
    package com.example.hell;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    EditText ed;
     EditText ed1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String result = null;
             InputStream is = null;
             EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             String v1 = editText.getText().toString();
             EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
             String v2 = editText1.getText().toString();

             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",v1));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",v2));
             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
             try{
                 HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login.php");
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();

                 Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             try{
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 String line = null;
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                 {
                         sb.append(line + "\n");
                         Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Menu.class);
                         startActivity(i);
                 }

                 is.close();
                 result=sb.toString();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }

             try{


                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                 String ch=object.getString("re");
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 if(ch.equals("success"))
                 {

                   Intent i=new Intent("com.example.hell.MainActivity");
                   startActivity(i);
                 }


                 else
                 {

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record is not available.. Enter valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }


         }
         catch(JSONException e)
         {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }  


        }
        });
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

please help me out with the solution.

here is the PHP code of  login form

```
<?php
session_start();
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
$password=$_REQUEST["password"];
if($id==NULL&& $password==NULL)
 {
    $r["re"]="Enter the Registered Id and password!!!";
                 print(json_encode($r));
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 else
 {
  $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("couldn't connect");
  mysql_select_db("android") or die("couldn't find database");
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * From profile WHERE username='$email'");
  $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
   while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $dbusername=$rows['id'];
      $dbpassword=$rows['password'];
    }
      if($id==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
      {
   //  echo("you're in! <a href='member.php'>click</a>here to enter");
     //   $_SESSION ['email']=$dbusername;
     $r["re"]="success";
     print(json_encode($r));
      }
      else
      {
         $r["re"]="fail";
     print(json_encode($r));
      }
   }


?>
```

and my logcat shows the following errors.

```
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904): Process: com.example.hell, PID: 904
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at com.example.hell.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:100)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-23 05:50:37.970: E/AndroidRuntime(904):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


thank u...but it shows stop working after click submit button
```

thank u...but it shows stop working after click submit button
I would need to retrieve data to display on android emulator

package com.example.main; import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.InputStream; import java.io.InputStreamReader; import java.text.NumberFormat; import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity; import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; import org.apache.http.NameValuePair; import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity; import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair; import org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint; import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.os.StrictMode; import android.util.Log; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class select extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View view)
          {
             String result = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
            String v1 = editText.getText().toString();
            EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e2);

            EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e3);

      ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f1",v1));
                try
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/select.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");


                }
            catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            //convert response to string
                try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");

                    }
                    is.close();

                    result=sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            //parse json data
            try{


                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                    String ch=object.getString("re");
                    if(ch.equals("success"))
                    {

                       JSONObject no = object.getJSONObject("0");
                    String w= no.getString("f2");
                    long e=no.getLong("f3");

                    editText1.setText(w);
                   String myString = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(e);


                    editText2.setText(myString);

                      }


                    else
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record is not available.. Enter valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


            }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


       }
       });



 }
```

}

Comment: This is something about php code . so you have to show that infomation

Comment: thank you. i have added the php code just now.

Comment: thank u...but it shows stop working after click submit button

Comment: am sorry...but i need to know about it sorry i write my code as print (json_encode($row)) in my php code again it shows error as jsonarray fail...

Answer (score 0):

OK. I saw in the php code you only return $r to the client , so that it dont contains any thing about profile. 
So you should return $row ( encode into json)

Comment: am sorry...but i need to know about it sorry i write my code as print (json_encode($row)) in my php code again it shows error as jsonarray fail...

Comment: @ArjunViswanathan where you do this? out of while loop? pls remember that $row only exists in while loop. pls check that

Comment: i would need one more help...data is retriving from database but it is not display in android emulator...